# SQL Server : update column from table if one of the record >= X

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, int

I need help in updating one of my columns in an existing temp table everytime one of the metric is >= 4.

Below is my query that I am working on:

```
DECLARE @Met NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Met = 'MET'

DECLARE @NotMet NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @NotMet = 'NOT MET'

UPDATE #TmpTbl
SET Score_Oct = (CASE 
                    WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND CAST(Score_Oct AS INT) >= 4 
                       THEN @NotMet 
                       ELSE @Met 
                 END),
    Score_Nov = (CASE 
                    WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND CAST(Score_Nov AS INT) IN (4, 5, 6) 
                       THEN @NotMet 
                       ELSE @Met 
                 END),
    Score_Dec = (CASE 
                    WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND Score_Dec IN ('4', '5', '6') 
                       THEN @NotMet 
                       ELSE @Met 
                 END),
    Score_Jan = (CASE 
                    WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND Score_Jan IN ('4', '5', '6') 
                       THEN @NotMet 
                       ELSE @Met 
                 END),
    Score_Feb = (CASE 
                    WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND Score_Feb IN ('4', '5', '6') 
                       THEN @NotMet 
                       ELSE @Met 
                 END)
    ,Score_Mar = (CASE WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND Score_Mar      IN ('4','5','6') THEN @NotMet ELSE @Met END)
    ,Score_Apr = (CASE WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND Score_Apr      IN ('4','5','6') THEN @NotMet ELSE @Met END)
    ,Score_May = (CASE WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND Score_May      IN ('4','5','6') THEN @NotMet ELSE @Met END)
    ,Score_Jun = (CASE WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND Score_Jun      IN ('4','5','6') THEN @NotMet ELSE @Met END)
    ,Score_Jul = (CASE WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND Score_Jul      IN ('4','5','6') THEN @NotMet ELSE @Met END)
    ,Score_Aug = (CASE WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND Score_Aug      IN ('4','5','6') THEN @NotMet ELSE @Met END)
    ,Score_Sep = (CASE WHEN ([Type] LIKE '%Metric%') AND Score_Sep      IN ('4','5','6') THEN @NotMet ELSE @Met END)
WHERE
    Metric = 'Balance Scorecard'
```

I have been trying different combination (casting, treating the field as INT, text, etc)  but to no avail. Is there anything that I missed?

Below is the result set:

```
Metric             Type                   Result_Oct    Score_Oct   Result_Nov     Score_Nov
AA                 1.Monthly Metric       3             3           NULL            NULL
BB                 1.Monthly Metric       292           3           300             3
CC                 1.Monthly Metric       3             3           NULL            NULL
DD                 2.Half Yearly Metric   70            3           NULL            NULL
EE                 2.Half Yearly Metric   100           1           67              4
Balance Scorecard  3.Accountability       NULL          MET         NULL            MET
```

The Balance Scoredcard should be "NOT MET" for "Score_nov" as EE metric is >=4 but it seems like the query cannot acknowledge the numbers. Is it because of the fields that is null?

Comment: Can you provide some sample source data?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the values are in different *rows*.  So, you need a `JOIN` to bring them together.

Here is the example for Nov.  The other months are basically the same:

```
UPDATE t
    SET score_Nov = (CASE WHEN CAST(tt.Score_Nov AS INT) >= 4
                          THEN @NotMet ELSE @Met
                     END)
    FROM #TmpTbl t CROSS JOIN
         #TmpTbl tt
    WHERE t.metric = 'Balance Scorecard' AND tt.metric = 'EE';
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, how can I make it wildcard? In your example, this is solely if the metric is "EE". I don't want to single-handedly each record. Is there another way?I need it to iterate on the each month for all metrics..

Comment: @lucas . . . You can handle all months, simply adding more columns to the `set` clause.  I don't understand what you mean by additional metrics.

Comment: Hi Gordon, it is the where clause that I am concerned. this has too look through the column 'metric' (e.g. AA,BB,CC,DD,EE). This is a dynamic field and I wouldn't know the lists.